# $f:\mathbb{N} \to M$ is surjective $\leftrightarrow$ $\exists$ $g:M \to \mathbb{N}$ injective with $(f \circ g)(x)=x$ $\forall x \in M$

Tags: functions

Prove:
$f:\mathbb{N} \to M$ is surjective $\leftrightarrow$ $\exists$ $g:M \to \mathbb{N}$ injective with $(f \circ g)(x)=x$  $\forall x \in M$

I think that I already proved one direction ($\leftarrow$) of the equivalence. But how to prove ($\rightarrow$)
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Let us suppose that $f:\mathbb{N}\longrightarrow M$ is surjective. Then, for every $m\in M$ there exist $\{n_1,...,n_i\}\in\mathbb{N}$, $i\geq 1$, such that $f(n_i)=m$ for every $i$. Thus, let us define $g:M\longrightarrow\mathbb{N}$ as
$$ g(m):=n_i$$
for some $i$. We have that
$$(f\circ g)(m)=f(g(m))=f(n_i)=m$$
for every $m\in M$. Moreover, if we suppose that $g(m_1)=g(m_2)$, we obtain
$$m_1=f(g(m_1))=f(g(m_2))=m_2,$$
i.e. $g$ is injective.

Comment: Yeah all right, thats pretty clear thank you! Is the first half of the proof you can see in the picture I added correct?

Comment: @Analysis_Mark It looks correct, although, by definition of $(f\circ g)$, the element you called $a$ is in fact $x$. For every $x\in M$, $(f\circ g)(x)=x$. Therefore, $f(g(x))=x$, which means that, for every $x\in M$, there exists $n:=g(x)\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $f(n)=x$.

Comment: I just did the task again and read your answer again, but I can't understand why we are allowed to say that $(f\circ g)(m)=f(g(m))=f(n_i)=m$ $\forall m\in M$. I mean we said that $g(m)=n_i$ for some i. So if we have $f(n_i)$ we don't have every n anymore. Why are we allowed to say that $f(n_i)= m$ $\forall m\in M$?

Comment: @Analysis_Mark I will try to be clearer: by hypothesis, $f$ is surjective, which means, by definition, that, for every $m\in M$, the set $f^{-1}(m)$ is not the empty set. In other words, for every $m\in M$, there exists at least one element $n_m\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $f(n_m)=m$. Therefore, for every $m\in M$, we can define $g(m)=n_m$, which is well defined, injective, and is such that $(f\circ g)(m)=f(n_m)=m$, by construction.

Comment: Allright. So we construct an injective function g, that is mapping all $m\in M$ to exactly one of their inverse images. We may lose some $n_i$, if f is only surjective, but the $n_i$ that are left are already enough to get all elements of M as a value of f. Right?

Comment: @Analysis_Mark Yes. More precisely, since $g$ is injective, it is a bijection between $M$ and $g(M)\subset\mathbb{N}$, and $(f\circ g)(M)=M$.